# How to solve setOnItemClickListener() in two HortzListView from same activity been mixed up data transfer?

Tags: android, android-intent, parse-platform

I Have used two `HortzListView` from `androidq.jar` file, but the problem was it always resulted in mixed up data on `HortzListView.setOnItemClickListener()` when transferring data to other activity. I need a result to data transfer for which the item was clicked exactly. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

```
/* Deals Horizontal list view initiation * /

   HorzListView hotDealsListView, newDealsListView;
    hotDealsListView = (HorzListView) findViewById(R.id.hotDealsList);
    newDealsListView = (HorzListView) findViewById(R.id.newDealsList);

    if (CheckNetworkConnection.isOnline(this)) {
    ParseQuery < ParseObject > dealsQuery = new    ParseQuery(AppBazaarConstants.APP_BAZAAR_MAIN_PRODUCT);

dealsQuery.whereEqualTo(AppBazaarConstants.CATEGORY,AppBazaarConstants.HOT_DEALS);

dealsQuery.setLimit(4);
dealsQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback < ParseObject > () {...}

dealsAdapter = new DealsAdapter(HomeActivity.this, R.layout.deals_single_item, dealsArrayList);

hotDealsListView.setAdapter(dealsAdapter);

/*Intent with this item ClickListener Indication 1*/

/***************  Problem or Indication 1 ******************************/

hotDealsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new 

AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

     @Override

public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > parent, View view, int position, long id) {
simpleCatgoryUtil = dealsArrayList.get(position);

intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, DealsDetailActivity.class);                                 switchDeals(HomeActivity.this,intent,simpleCatgoryUtil);
   } 

else {

Message.messageShort(HomeActivity.this, "No HotDeals Product Available");

}

} else {

Message.messageShort(HomeActivity.this, e.getMessage());

 }

}

});

} else {

Message.messageAlert(this, AppBazaarConstants.OK, AppBazaarConstants.CHECK_FOR_NETWORK_CONNECTION);
 }


if (CheckNetworkConnection.isOnline(this)) {

ParseQuery < ParseObject > dealsQuery = new ParseQuery <> (AppBazaarConstants.APP_BAZAAR_MAIN_PRODUCT);


dealsQuery.whereEqualTo(AppBazaarConstants.CATEGORY, AppBazaarConstants.NEW_DEALS);

dealsQuery.setLimit(4);

dealsQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback < ParseObject > () {....}

dealsAdapter = new DealsAdapter(HomeActivity.this, R.layout.deals_single_item, dealsArrayList);

newDealsListView.setAdapter(dealsAdapter);


/*Intent with this item ClickListener Indication 2*/

/****************** Problem Or Indicator 2 *******************************/

newDealsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { 

 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > parent, View view, int position,       long id) {

simpleCatgoryUtil = dealsArrayList.get(position);
intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, DealsDetailActivity.class);                                switchDeals(HomeActivity.this,intent,simpleCatgoryUtil);

 }

});
} else {
Message.messageShort(HomeActivity.this, "No HotDeals Product Available");
}
} else {

Message.messageShort(HomeActivity.this, e.getMessage());

}

}

});

} else {
Message.messageAlert(this, AppBazaarConstants.OK, AppBazaarConstants.CHECK_FOR_NETWORK_CONNECTION);

}




/*This is the common method*/

/*Indication 1 and Indication 2 item clicklistner data get mixed up*/

private  static void switchDeals(Context context ,Intent intent , 
SimpleCatgoryUtil simpleCatgoryUtil){ 

intent.putExtra( AppBazaarConstants.OBJECT_ID, simpleCatgoryUtil.getObjectId());

intent.putExtra(AppBazaarConstants.PRODUCT, simpleCatgoryUtil.getProduct());................     


context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Good lord, please do some editing (formatting) on this and clarify your question.

Comment: @Ascorbin I went ahead and fixed the code formatting. ("What year is it?") My edit is currently pending review.

Comment: > Horizontal List view

Comment: HorzListView hotDealsListView, newDealsListView;

Comment: Problem or  Indicator 1 and Problem or Indicator 2 and Common Method are real problem part in the code

Comment: @IronFlare oh boy!! its 3015. :). vinayagam.D what really do you want i dont see nothing

Comment: The Problem was on setOnItemClicklistener(), The two horizontal listview item gets mixed while intenting i.e., the data of hotdeals and newdeals setOnItemClickListenter() data. E.g., Suppose if Click on hot deals item, the data of new deals item get displayed in next activity.

Comment: The problem was that I was referring the newsDeal and hotDeals was referring the same array list and when  I create two different array list variable the on click listener was occuing as expected

Comment: First I declared like this  ArrayList arrayList  and referring newDealsArray and hotDealsArray with this arrayList---> this was a problem; Then I solve it by creating ArrayList newDealsArrayList and hotDealsArrayList

Comment: Thank For your support guys. I may require your help in future thanks in advance